# wagtail setting up a first site

Tags: python, content-management-system, wagtail

I'm using the wagtaildemo vagrant box and following [this guide](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0b1/getting_started/creating_your_project.html). when I execute runserver from the mysite directory it's still running the the code from the demo directory instead of from mysite.

the page being displayed shows the heading wagtail demo and a slideshow with bird images.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'demo code', but I'm assuming you mean you are seeing the 'Welcome to Wagtail' screen rather than you're own custom homepage.

If so, you need to set the 'root page' in the Wagtail admin to be your homepage, rather than the Wagtail admin.

Click 'Settings' > 'Sites' > 'Your site' > 'Root page', then select your actual homepage.

Note: It's a good idea to move your homepage to the root of the site. Then once you've changed the 'Root page' you can delete the 'Welcome to Wagtail' page.

If this isn't what you're looking for please expand your answer to include exactly what you mean by 'demo code'.